# The best and most secure way to echo results with pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hi i am new to PDO and i just learn how to make a Query, i have read a lot about this everywhere on the internet, without luck, and then i tryed this, but i am still wondering if this is the right way to do it? How is the best way to make this to a class, because when i tryed, i did not got any kind of error, and any respond either.

```
<?php

require_once 'dbconfig.php';



// (echo test) $name_structure='%s';
// (echo test) $title_structure='%s';

try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

$sql = 'SELECT * 
        FROM portfolio';

$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array('%son'));
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while ($r = $q->fetch()) {
    echo sprintf($name_structure,  $r['name']);
    echo sprintf($title_structure, $r['title']);
    echo sprintf($description_structure, $r['description']);
    echo sprintf($img_structure, $r['img']);
    echo sprintf($project_end_structure, $r['project_end']);



}
} catch (PDOException $pe) {
die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $pe->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you forgot to explain what is "this" you are trying, here are two possible scenarios:

In case "this" is for getting all the records from database, the code would be

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$stmt = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM portfolio');
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['name'];
    echo $row['title'];
    echo $row['description'];
    echo $row['img'];
    echo $row['project_end'];
}
```

in case "this" is about selecting only certain records, code it as follows

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM portfolio WHERE name LIKE ?');
$stmt->execute(array('%son'));
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['name'];
    echo $row['title'];
    echo $row['description'];
    echo $row['img'];
    echo $row['project_end'];
}
```

> How is the best way to make this to a class,

PDO is **already a class,** mind you. So, insead of making it into another, just learn how to use PDO.

> i have read a lot about this everywhere on the internet, without luck,

Here you go, I wrote a tutorial that makes sense (at least for anyone who have basic PHP/SQL training), [The only proper guide on PDO](http://phpdelusions.net/pdo)

Comment: thanks for the fantastic response, it was just what I needed! and good guide you've written, as I will read immediately!